# Electric field due to two opposite charges

Tags: electric-fields

We know that The net electric field due to two equal and oppsite charges is 0.

But let us consider a charge +Q in an isolated system. An electric field E will be emitted by it.

Similarly, a -Q charge will absorb an electric field E.

When both are in the same system then the magnitude  field emitted by +Q and -Q should be added.

So can it be said that an electric field 2E is between +Q and -Q.

If an electric field E is generated by +Q towards -Q

And an electric field E is generated by -Q towards itself.

If both are in same direction, shouldn't both be aded to give 2E between them.

Of course the net will remain 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The net electric field due to two equal and oppsite charges is 0.

This is only true if the two charges are located in the exact same location. For example, a block of copper sitting on your lab bench contains an equal amount of electrons and protons, occupying the same volume of space, so the block of copper produces no net external electric field.

But if you separate the two charges from each other, they will produce a non-zero electric field everywhere in space. (This field will get very weak, but still non-zero, at locations much further from the charges than the distance between the charges)

It's actually easier to produce "zero net field" using two equal and same-signed charges.

For example, if I have two point charges with charge $+Q$ at locations $+x$ and $-x$ on the x-axis, then they will produce zero net field at the origin, since the field from one charge will be pointing right and the field from the other will be pointing left.

> So can it be said that an electric field 2E is between +Q and -Q.
>
> If an electric field E is generated by +Q towards -Q
>
> And an electric field E is generated by -Q towards itself.
>
> If both are in same direction, shouldn't both be aded to give 2E between them.

Exactly.

> Of course the net will remain 0.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by this.

It is true in the sense of Gauss's Law. If you construct a closed surface around the two charges then the net electric flux through the surface will be 0.

But that's not the same as saying the "net field" is 0.

The net field is measured at a point in space, and is non-zero everywhere in your system. The net flux is measured over a surface, and can be zero if you construct the surface to contain the two charges.

Comment: "But if you separate the two charges from each other, they will produce a non-zero electric field everywhere in space." If this is true then what about dipole in a closed Gaussian surface. Would it produce a net electric field ? If yes then what about Gauss's Law?

Comment: @UtkarshSharma, Gauss's Law is about the net flux through a surface. It doesn't tell you much about the net field at any particular point.

Comment: "It is true in the sense of Gauss's Law. If you construct a surface around the two charges, symmetric about the mid-point between the charges and the line between the charges, then the net electric flux through the surface will be 0.

But that's not the same as saying the "net field" is 0." Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all electric field due to a system of charges and an electric field due to a single charge are two different concepts.

> We know that The net electric field due to two equal and oppsite charges is 0.

Where do you saw the above statement?We can say that algebraic sum of equal and opposite charges is zero but it does not imply that the net electric field produced by them is zero until and unless they are at the same position.In fact if they are separated by some distance then there wouldn't be even any single position in space(except infinity) where electric field is zero.

Comment: "We know that The net electric field due to two equal and oppsite charges is 0." That's what our teacher told us so I was confused. Now I know that they have to be at same position. Thanks for help!