# The role of valence electrons in the electric field of atoms

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, atoms

I've read somewhere that hydrogen forms a strong electric field because it's a really small atom and it doesn't have any valence electrons.

My question would be, how does this conclude that it has a strong electric field? I don't see how these things are related to how strong the electic field is, espescially the valence electrons part

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electric field due to a hydrogen atom](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/509370/)

Comment: The related post has nothing to do with my question, whoever closed my question obviously only read the title like always.....

Comment: What qualifies as a “strong” electric field? Have you calculated the field at the surface of the proton?

Comment: @Ghoster Well, relatively strong. The question is more about the role of valence electrons in electric fields. Note that all this is in the context of hydrogen bonding.